# How to toggle between previous buffer in a given window (e.g toggle-previous-buffer-in-window)?

Tags: buffers, window

How can I make Emacs toggle between the previous buffer within a single window (e.g. ignoring buffer changes in other windows)?

Comment: Like this?:  `(previous-buffer)` [*It is bound to <XF86Back>, C-x <C-left>, C-x <left>, <menu-bar> <buffer> <previous-buffer>.*] and `(next-buffer)` [*It is bound to C-x <C-right>, C-x <right>, <menu-bar> <buffer> <next-buffer>.*]

Comment: These commands were the first things I tried. They appear to use a global stack to decide what the next and previous buffers were. I'm interested in remembering the previous buffer for a particular window.

Comment: Perhaps this is not possible without [window-local-variables?](http://root42.blogspot.com/2012/08/an-argument-for-emacs-window-local.html)

Comment: I found this question and was really excited! Less excited when I saw there was no answer :(

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are looking for [winner-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WinnerMode).

Winner mode, when activated, allows you to navigate windows, together with the buffer contents that was there at the time, by `C-c left` and `C-c right`.

Comment: I've used winner-mode in the past, and I don't think it does what I am describing. Basically, I'm looking for a `(previous-window-local-buffer)` or a `(toggle-window-local-buffer)`. The latter naming makes it more obvious I'm looking for a command which switches between one of two states.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a keyboard macro

```lisp
(define-key global-map [(control tab)] (kbd "C-x b <return>"))
```